# Iterating with fopen in C

Tags: c

This is my first C program- I'm trying to create a new text file on my  desktop (called 0.txt - 999.txt) every 3 seconds. Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

  int i;
  char txt_files[1000];

  for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {

    sprintf(txt_files, "%d.txt", i);
    puts(txt_files);

    FILE *f;
    f = fopen("~/Desktop/" + txt_files, "w"); 
    fprintf(f, "Testing..\n");

    sleep(3); 

  }
}
```

I've tried using fopen multiple ways, but I can't figure out how to pass it the correct path. I thought it should be "~/Desktop/txt_files[i]" but that doesn't work. After googling around I found out how to use sprintf to format the file names, but I don't know how to use that in fopen. Any ideas?

Comment: `fopen` doesn't understand ~ - only shells do. You have to use the actual path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost got it right, you use the `sprintf()` function to generate the string from a number, didn't you think of generating the whole filename?

This is what i fixed

1. Generated the complete file path with the use of `snprintf()`, i prefer `snprintf()` because it prevents a buffer overflow.
2. Got the home path from the `HOME` environment variable, the `~` is expanded by the shell, but it cannot be used in a c program for the purpose of expanding `$HOME`.
3. Added a check for the `fopen()` call, you should make sure the file was really opened before attempting to write to it.
4. Added a missing `fclose()` after writing to the file.

Here is a fixed version of your code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    char filename[256];
    const char *home;

    home = getenv("HOME");
    if (home == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "could not read env variable $HOME\n");
        return -1;
    }

    for (i = 0 ; i < 1000 ; i++)
    {
        FILE *file;

        snprintf(filename, sizeof(filename), "%s/Desktop/%d.txt", home, i);
        puts(filename);

        file = fopen(filename, "w");
        if (file != NULL)
        {
            fprintf(file, "Testing..\n");
            fclose(file);
        }
        else
            fprintf(stderr, "could not create the file...\n");
        sleep(3);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need the `strcat` function in `string.h` to produce the complete file path.
I konw the **+** operator can merge strings in Python. But `C` doesn't support this as far as i know.

```
char file_path[1000]; // or just char file_path[1000] = "~/Desktop/"?
file_path[0] = '\0';
strcat(file_path, "~/Desktop/");
strcat(file_path, txt_files);
f = fopen(file_path, "w");
```

Furthermore, you should use `fclose` function to close the file after some operation.

Comment: You must encourage good practices for new programmers, if you do you would find much less bugs in software, and that would be great. Apparently many of the bugs come from the fact that many programmers deliberately write unsafe code. Adding checks for every possible invalid pointer operation, would prevent a lot of headache.

Comment: It would make more sense to simply `strcpy` "~/Desktop/" into `file_path` and not have to set the first character to '/0'

Comment: @Namfuak no, because the OP will use the `sprintf()` function anyway to generate a string from the integer, so why not use it to generate the full string? see my answer. Although of course 1 `strcpy()` + 1 `strcat()` makes more sense than 2 `strcat()`s

Comment: @iharob thank you for your advise, i am a new programmer too.

Comment: @Namfuak I know another str function because of your comment. Thank you.